# Is CIDR notation allowed in nginx server_name?

Tags: nginx

Is CIDR notation allowed in nginx server_name?

Nginx documentation doesn't mention anything about this and I am not getting any errors, just a warning.

Config:

```
server_name 
  localhost
  27.0.0.1

  172.31.0.0/16

  some.domain.com;
```

I am getting this warning:

```
nginx: [warn] server name "172.31.0.0/16" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/some_config_file:45
```

I assume it does not not understand it as an ip address range. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

```
Server Name

 ... may be defined using exact names, wildcard names, or regular expressions.
```

A specific IP does fall into the exact names but not a range. Though you most likely could get it to work with a regular expression but not sure of the use case.